# When power button on Android Tablet is pressed, surface view camera freezes and does not release

Tags: android, android-camera

When my application is opened and I press power `Button` and reopen the Tablet, the `Camera` hangs. I have tried setting the SurfaceView Camera on `onResume()` method again, but was not able to solve the problem and have tried to start `(camera1.startpreview())` but still I am facing the same problem.

My Surface View's camera code is:

```
SurfaceView cameraPreview1;
SurfaceHolder previewHolder1;
public static  Camera camera2;
boolean inPreview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  inPreview = false;

  cameraPreview1 = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview1);
  previewHolder1 = cameraPreview1.getHolder();
  previewHolder1.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
  previewHolder1.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

 }
@Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();


      camera2=Camera.open(1);
      mPicture1 = getPictureCallback();


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {


      super.onPause();
        //when on Pause, release camera in order to be used from other applications

        releaseCamera();
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        // stop and release camera
        if (camera2 != null) {
            camera2.release();
            camera2 = null;
        }
    }

     SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                camera2.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder1);  
            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters=camera2.getParameters();
            Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(width, height, parameters);

            if (size!=null) {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                camera2.setParameters(parameters);
                camera2.startPreview();
                inPreview=true;
            }
    }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // not used

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `setPreviewDisplay()` in `surfaceCreated()`, but the surface isn't necessarily destroyed and recreated when you turn the screen off and back on with the power button ([see notes here](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html)).  I don't think the Camera is hung, I think it just isn't sending the preview frames to the Surface, because `surfaceCreated()` isn't being called a second time.

The way to fix this is to detect if the Surface has already been created, by setting a static variable in `surfaceCreated()` and clearing it in `surfaceDestroyed()`.  If the Surface is already set up when you enter `onResume()`, you need to call `setPreviewDisplay()` on the new Camera object.

Grafika's "[texture from camera](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/TextureFromCameraActivity.java)" activity demonstrates tracking the Surface with a static variable.  FWIW, Grafika's "continuous capture" activity [gets this wrong](https://github.com/google/grafika/issues/24) as well.